# text inside query banner

Tags: jquery, banner

I am trying to make a JQuery banner. My code looks like this:
Here is a video of my banner until now:
[Banner Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Das2dyBvA_U&feature=youtu.be)

My code looks like this:

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bannerTest.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $(".banner").animate({height: "300px"}, 600);
        $(".banner").animate({width: "100%"}, 350, function()
           {
            $(".banner-blue").animate({height: "300px"}, 700);
           });

        });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="banner">
    <div class="banner-blue">test

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.banner {
    background:#98bf21;
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    margin:6px;
}

.banner-blue {
    background:#0000ff;
    position:absolute;
    width: 300px;
}
```

When the blue square in the left side has loaded, I would like to have some text that fades in. But I am really in doubt where to put it in the code? In the class: banner-blue I have put in the word "test". When the site is loading, it says test from the beginning. I am thinking I have to make a script, where there is a delay on the text? If that is the case, I dont know how to make the link to the script, when there is already a class called "banner-blue" in the same div?

Hope somebody can help me.

Beste Regards
Mads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the callback-function of the `.animate()`-function:

**jQuery**

```
$(".banner-blue").animate({
    height: "300px"
}, 700, function(){
    $('.hidden').fadeIn(); //fade the text-element in after the animation is completed
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="banner-blue">
     <p class="hidden">test</p> //use any element with a class or ID to reference to your text
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o0cxaLsu/)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have element that fades in, you have to hide it first.

```
.banner-blue {
    display: none;
    height: 300px;
}

$('.banner-blue').fadeIn(700);
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".banner").animate({
    height: "300px"
  }, 600);
  $(".banner").animate({
    width: "100%"
  }, 350, function() {
    $(".banner-blue").show().animate({height: '300px'}, 700);
  });

});
```

```css
.banner {
  background: #98bf21;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 6px;
}
.banner-blue {
  background: #0000ff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 0px;
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner-blue">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot for your answer. I was thinking that the text first should come after the blue box is down to the bottom. Is that just the miliseconds that should go more late?

Comment: @MadsKristensen Text itself don't have any animation. Only blue box is shown and then resized it's height to 300px. Can you please update your question with step-by-step explanation of animation process?

Answer (score 0):

[Check here](http://codepen.io/Sonick/pen/HthaI)

```
-webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
-moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
-ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
```

i think this will solve your problem